# Warning: a possible image without description

Tags: floats, texlive, warnings, texlive-2017

I employ TexLive 2017. I use the following piece of codes in my tex.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\epsfig{file=fig/a.eps, width=1.0\columnwidth}
\caption{a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\columnwidth}
\epsfig{file=fig/b.eps, width=1.0\columnwidth}
\caption{b}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace*{-5pt}
\caption{\bf a versus b}
\end{figure}
```

It leads to a warning, which complains "A possible image without description on input line ...". I wonder why this warning happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Thanks for your MWE. Note that it is better to have it highlighted as a code block. Put four empty spaces at the beginning of your lines rather than backtick escapes, as I did in my edit. And please  make your next question MWE fully compiliable, adding the  `documentclass` and `\begin{document}`and `\end{document}` lines.

Comment: `\epsfig` is outdated so far I know. Try to use the `graphicx` package with `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the warning you quoted, I assume that you use the `acmart` document clss.

To quote from [the manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) of version 1.56:

> 2.6  Descriptions of images
>   Blockquote
>
> Some readers of ACM publications might be visually challenged.  These
>   readers might  use a voice-over software to read aloud the
>   papers.  It is important to provided them a description of each image
>   used in the paper. The  command `\Description[<short description>]{<long description>}` should  be placed inside every figure ,
>   teaserfigure or marginfigure environment to provide a description of
>   the image(s) used in the figure. Unlike `\caption` , which is used along-
>   side the image, `\Description` is intended to be used instead of the
>   image [...]
>   At present the lack of descriptions generates a warning at compilation.

Comment: TLDR; ACM template requires that you add `\Description` to help voice-over software to read aloud paper.